# how do I labels to the axis in this d3 example

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I figured out how to enter my data into this d3 chart but I can't seem to figure out how to put labels on both the x and y axis. I am looking to put strings as the values in the x-axis. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

</style>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="grouped"> Grouped</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="stacked" checked> Stacked</label>
</form>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var n = 3, // number of layers
    m = 3, // number of samples per layer
    stack = d3.layout.stack(),
    // layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function() { return bumpLayer(m, .1); })),
    layers = [
                [
                    {"x":0,"y":200,"y0":0},
                    {"x":1,"y":150,"y0":0},
                    {"x":2,"y":100,"y0":0}
                ],
                [
                    {"x":0,"y":100,"y0":1},
                    {"x":1,"y":80,"y0":1},
                    {"x":2,"y":70,"y0":1}
                ],
                [
                    {"x":0,"y":30,"y0":2},
                    {"x":1,"y":40,"y0":2},
                    {"x":2,"y":50,"y0":2}
                ]
            ];
    yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
    yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

console.log(layers);


var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(m))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .08);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yStackMax])
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range(["#aad", "#556"]);

// var formatAxis = d3.format("  0");
// var axis = d3.svg.axis()
//         .scale(xScale)
//         .tickFormat(formatAxis)
//         .ticks(3)
//         .tickValues([100, 200, 300]) //specify an array here for values
//         .orient("bottom");

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(6)
    .orient("bottom");


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("y", height)
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", 0);

rect.transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);

var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  d3.select("input[value=\"grouped\"]").property("checked", true).each(change);
}, 2000);

function change() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  if (this.value === "grouped") transitionGrouped();
  else transitionStacked();
}

function transitionGrouped() {
  y.domain([0, yGroupMax]);

  rect.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
      .attr("x", function(d, i, j) { return x(d.x) + x.rangeBand() / n * j; })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand() / n)
    .transition()
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });
}

function transitionStacked() {
  y.domain([0, yStackMax]);

  rect.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .transition()
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());
}

// Inspired by Lee Byron's test data generator.
// function bumpLayer(n, o) {

//   function bump(a) {
//     var x = 1 / (.1 + Math.random()),
//         y = 2 * Math.random() - .5,
//         z = 10 / (.1 + Math.random());
//     for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
//       var w = (i / n - y) * z;
//       a[i] += x * Math.exp(-w * w);
//     }
//   }

//   var a = [], i;
//   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = o + o * Math.random();
//   for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) bump(a);
//   return a.map(function(d, i) { return {x: i, y: Math.max(0, d)}; });
// }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into a tickFormat? See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc5y42t9/1).

Here is a code of interest:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(2)
    .tickPadding(6)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return "test" + d; })
    .orient("bottom");
```